# Cling Upnp scan causes ClassDefNotFoundError Jetty

Tags: java, android, jetty, android-cling

I am working on an Android app, which is using Cling to perform an UPNP scan. Its logging that it receives packets but then it crashes with a NoClassDefFound exception for Jetty.

Below is the code I am using to perform the scan

```
ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            upnpService = (AndroidUpnpService)service;

            upnpService.getRegistry().addListener(listener);
            upnpService.getControlPoint().search();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            upnpService = null;
        }
    };

    public HueBridgeSearch(Context context, Activity activity)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void startBridgeSearch()
    {
        // Fix the logging integration between java.util.logging and Android internal logging
        org.seamless.util.logging.LoggingUtil.resetRootHandler(
                new FixedAndroidLogHandler()
        );
        Logger.getLogger("org.fourthline.cling").setLevel(Level.ALL);
        listener = new RegistryListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryStarted(Registry registry, RemoteDevice remoteDevice)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Remote Device Discovery Started: " + remoteDevice.getDisplayString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryFailed(Registry registry, RemoteDevice remoteDevice, Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Remote device discovery failed: " + remoteDevice.getDisplayString());
                Log.d(TAG, "Remote device discovery failed: " + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void remoteDeviceAdded(Registry registry, RemoteDevice remoteDevice)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Added Found Device: " + remoteDevice.getDisplayString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void remoteDeviceUpdated(Registry registry, RemoteDevice remoteDevice)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Updated Found Device: " + remoteDevice.getDisplayString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void remoteDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, RemoteDevice remoteDevice)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void localDeviceAdded(Registry registry, LocalDevice localDevice)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Local Added Found Device: " + localDevice.getDisplayString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void localDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, LocalDevice localDevice)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeShutdown(Registry registry)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterShutdown()
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.class);
        //intent.setClassName("org.fourthline.cling.android", "org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl");
        boolean success = context.bindService(intent,
            serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    }
```

Below is my gradle build file dependencies

```
  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      compile files('libs/cling-core-2.1.0.jar')
      compile files('libs/seamless-util-1.1.1.jar')
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
      compile files('libs/jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar')
      compile files('libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar')
      compile files('libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.15.v20160210.jar')
      compile files('libs/seamless-http-1.1.1.jar')
  }
```

It compiles fine but then I get the following exception at runtime

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                        Process: com.BoardiesITSolutions.HueRulesAdvanced, PID: 9393
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server                                                                                           at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.resetServer(JettyServletContainer.java:165)                                                                                               at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.<init>(JettyServletContainer.java:57) at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.<clinit>(JettyServletContainer.java:55)at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration.createStreamServer(AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration.java:110)
at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.startAddressBasedTransports(RouterImpl.java:427)
at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.enable(RouterImpl.java:132)
at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidRouter.enable(AndroidRouter.java:91)
at org.fourthline.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:87)
at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl$1.<init>(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.onCreate(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2877)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the answer after a lot of trial and error. Instead of downloading the jar files into the lib folder and referencing the jars in the gradle file changing the build.gradle from:

```
 dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      compile files('libs/cling-core-2.1.0.jar')
      compile files('libs/seamless-util-1.1.1.jar')
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
      compile files('libs/jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar')
      compile files('libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar')
      compile files('libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.15.v20160210.jar')
      compile files('libs/seamless-http-1.1.1.jar')
  }
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/seamless-util-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/seamless-http-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/seamless-xml-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/cling-core-2.1.0.jar')
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8+'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8+'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8+'
}
```